# Friend overloaded insertion accessing data members of another class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

I have an assignment that I am stuck on and I have researched all day and come up empty handed:

I am working with two classes: `ClassA` must have a unique overloaded assignment and overloaded insertion.  `ClassB` must have a unique overloaded assignment, overloaded extraction, and overloaded insertion.

`ClassA` has data members: `int altitude`, `char code`, `string area`

`ClassB` has only an array of `classA`: `classA* data[30]`

All of the overloaded operators must be unique in each class. When I overload insertion or extraction for `ClassB` I get an error that the datamember is private which I assume is because the array I am reading into is of data type `ClassA`. I am not allowed to replicate friend functions from `ClassB` into `ClassA`. Is this even possible?

```
  class classB;

  class classA
  {
      friend class classB;

      friend ostream & operator<<(ostream&, const classA&);      
      void operator=(const classA&);

      int altitude;
      char code;
      string area;
  };

  class classB
  {
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const classB&);
      friend istream& operator>>(istream&, classB&);

      public:      
      void operator=(const classB&);      
      void sort();      

      private:
      classA* dataVals[30];      
  };
```

I am certain my overload functions are written correctly. We were given the basics of overloaded operators and the directions I just provided and that is all.

Comment: What do your insertion and extraction operators for class B look like?

Comment: Parsing this a bit more thoroughly this time. Some other function is going to use B's >> operator. B's >> is going to `new` a batch of As and stuff them into `dataVals`. Why not skip the friend relationship and give A a constructor that initializes A with values read in by B?

Comment: If you forget about `ClassB` for a moment, how do you create variables of `ClassA` in general? All its members are private and you haven't declared any constructors. Start with the test case `int main() { ClassA a(1, 'x', "Hello"); }` and make that compile first. Then continue with `ClassB`.

Comment: Friendship is not associative, so `istream& operator>>(istream&, classB&);` is not a friend of `classA`.

Comment: marking `classB` as friend can access private members of `classA` but insertion and extraction operator from `classB` cannot access `classA` private members in `classA` because those functions not mark as friend in `classA` my method is i would declared each of the two class an insertion and extraction operator

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't compile?